# Declaring more than 2 upstreams in the nginx config causes nginx to take 80 seconds to restart

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have 4 upstream blocks in my nginx config that I'm using depending on the incoming request's scheme or the geo location of the requesting client.

Every time I have to restart nginx it takes around 80 seconds to complete.  If I only have 3 upstreams declared it takes about 40 seconds, and with 2 upstreams it restarts pretty much immediately, like it normally does.

Reloads take 1/2 the time (40 seconds with 4 upstreams, 20 seconds with 3 upstreams).

There are no errors logged in the nginx error log, even on debug log level & if I run `/usr/sbin/nginx -t` it says the test is successful, but takes as long as a reload does.

Comment: Nginx resolves ip of all upstreams at (re)start. Check your dns

Comment: Bingo!  The DNS resolved wasn't working, got that back up & it's great.  Please post as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx resolves ip of all upstreams at (re)start. Check your DNS.